# I'm trying to set a responsive header background, but I'm having problems

Tags: html, css, header, responsive

So I'm trying to set this image: jordandevelop.com/test/img/header.jpg

as the header background. The problem I'm having is it won't respond to different screen resolutions. Below is the CSS I have for this current design.

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1600px;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url(../img/header.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Any advice would be great. Here's a link to the website: https://jordandevelop.com/test/

EDIT: Here is my current CSS for the header.

```
header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(../img/header.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

header .header-content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner hr {
    margin: 30px auto;
}

header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    header {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    header .header-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        padding: 0 50px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 1000px;
    }

    header .header-content .header-content-inner p {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        max-width: 80%;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you detail what you are trying to achieve by *respond*? Is it that you want the image to resize?

Comment: Try `contain` instead of `cover` (and make the background-color black)

Comment: @Aziz Now when I make my browser skinnier it has a huge black block.

Comment: So you want your background image to shrink when the resolution goes down?

Comment: @Angelo Yes. I need the entire image to be shown no matter what the resolution is. I updated the question with the current CSS.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work:

CSS: (add the following to your css code)

```
header{
   background: url(/test/img/header.jpg);
   background-size: cover;
}
```

or ( this one is responsive, preserves the whole image )

```
header{
   background: url(/test/img/header.jpg);
   background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Hope it helps, enjoy!

Comment: Now there's two large blocks of black on each side.

Comment: here you go : https://jsfiddle.net/1qsfumud/1/
the only difference is that the background-size property.

Comment: Is there any way to fix the way the image crops weirdly? The image can be bigger then browser in height.

Comment: The problem with the `100% 100%` approach is it could cause weird stretching. I think ideally the solution should retain the image's aspect ratio while having a width of `100%` and `auto` height.. the OP uses a fixed height, causing trouble.

Comment: @Aziz do you mind showing me? I tried doing what you said but it's still not working correctly.

Comment: @Jordan, what he meant is using `background-size:100% auto;`
instead of `background-size:100% 100%`.    

Alternatively, you can use `background-size:100%`, since the second value (the height) will be automatically set to `auto` if only one value is given.